# Spring Framework. Проблемы с преходом на другой сервер

Tags: spring, mvc, java

Здравствуйте, есть проект, написанный с помощью SpringFramework, сначала этот проект был расположен на сервере "windows server 2008 r2 32 bit", как перешли на "windows server 2012 64 bit", некоторые функции перестали работать на сайте (например, не загружает видео на сервер).
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Да в чем угодно. Вы логи смотрели? Может у процесса банально нет прав на запись в какую-то директорию или еще чего. Гадать можно бесконечно долго.

Comment: Все верно, без <strike>100 грамм</strike> логов не разобраться. Логи <strike>в студию</strike> покажите!